# Is it OK to run a trimmer without the plate-filter support?

Tags: small-engine, air-filter, choke

I've discovered the answer to this question by unfortunate experience, so I'm sharing it...

I have an XT200 Weedeater Trimmer.  In between the carburetor and the air filter is a thin metal plate called the Plate-Filter Support.  Unfortunately, in the process of repairing it, I misplaced this plate, and could no longer find it.  Is it ok to run the trimmer without this plate in place?  It doesn't appear all that critical.

Pictures of the part:

The plate:

[image]

([Source](http://www.ereplacementparts.com/images/part_p_235060_2060911851.gif))

The plate in place:

[image]

([Source](http://d2ydh70d4b5xgv.cloudfront.net/images/a/a/poulan-weedeater-xt-200-featherlite-choke-carb-muffler-filter-housing-used-4b1d7986157b49e9118ffd513fa2eaec.jpg))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No.

The manufacturers knew what they were doing.  They put the plate there for a reason: and that is so that the air filter doesn't get stuck in your choke and get torn up.  I discovered this by trying and getting the filter chewed up in the choke hole.  That being said, it's not that expensive of a mistake: it just requires the purchase of a new air filter.

**There was a reason they put the plate there; leave it there.**

Comment: If it's lost, and really needed as suggested... I'd probably just try to fab something up. It looks like an easy enough part to fab. Break out your dremel...